# Eliminate the Records based on the value in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I have a `table` as below,

```
id    record

1    5000tax
2    tax5000
3    tax5001
4    taxpro
5    val5005
```

I need to retrieve the records which started with letters. i wrote below query

```
select id, record, right(record,4) as code
from table
where left(record,1) like 'A' and 'Z'
```

output:

```
id  record   code

2   tax5000  5000
3   tax5001  5001
4   taxpro   xpro
5   val5005  5005
```

here i don't want to include the `records` which doesn't have any numbers in it.
i.e xpro.

I wrote below query

```
  select id, record, right(record,4) as code
    from table
    where left(record,1) like 'A' and 'Z'
    and record between '0' and '9'
```

It doesn't give any output.

thanks for the help

( P.S : Full text search property is disabled in the table)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `[0-9]` with `LIKE`:

```
select id, record, right(record, 4) as code
from table
where record like '[A-Z]%'
  and record like '%[0-9]%';
```

Or if it's always four digit numbers at the end, then:

```
select id, record, right(record, 4) as code
from table
where record like '[A-Z]%'
  and record like '%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]';
```

Comment: Interesting, @ThorstenKettner. Could you provide links for these "regular expressions" ?

Comment: @Mincong Huang: It's in the SQL Server docs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms179859(v=sql.120).aspx

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for `between`, not `like`:

```
select id, record, right(record,4) as code
from table
where left(record, 1) between 'A' and 'Z';
```

Alternatively, in SQL Server, you can do:

```
where record like '[A-Z]%'
```

or, if you are concerned about upper and lower case:

```
where record like '[A-Za-z]%'
```

Comment: I took `like` to be a mere typo. (Wouldn't the OP have gotten a syntax error otherwise?) The actual question was how to filter the results further such as to get only strings containing numbers :-)

Comment: thanks . bu i wonder why record between '0' and '9'  not works but record like %[0-9]%' works

Comment: @bmsqldev: The string 'tax5000' is not between '0' and '9'; it starts with a 't'.

Comment: I read the question as:  "I need to retrieve the records which started with letters.".

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
SELECT id, record 
FROM table
WHERE record BETWEEN 'a%' AND 'z%' 
      AND regexp_like(record,'[[:digit:]]')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @StartLetter TABLE (Id INT,Record VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO @StartLetter VALUES
(1,'5000tax'),
(2,'tax5000'),
(3,'tax5001'),
(4,'taxpro'),
(5,'val5005')

SELECT * FROM @StartLetter WHERE Record LIKE '[A-Z]%'
```

Answer (score 0):

I re-wrote the `query` as,

```
  select id, record, right(record,4) as code
  from table
  where left(record,1) between 'A' and 'Z'
  and record like '%[0-9]%'
```